# Problema con Kiuwan en un archivo .cs c#

Tags: c#

Primero que todo no sé si todos conocen la herramienta Kiuwan, esta es una herramienta que analiza el código que uno tiene y te indica las vulnerabilidades que hay.

En base a esto me está mostrando el siguiente problema:

> The product mixes trusted and untrusted data in the same data structure or structured message.
> A trust boundary violation occurs when a program blurs the line between what is trusted and what is untrusted.
> By combining trusted and untrusted data in the same data structure, it becomes easier for programmers
> to mistakenly trust unvalidated data. This violation may open attack avenues, like injection attacks,
> when the application takes untrusted data from the trusted domain without validation.

Ya después en el detalle me sale lo siguiente:

```
SOURCE DATA
Categoryuser_input
Container: System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult IdentificacionCedula(string mensaje)
Injection pointmodel

Linea 3,550
model.urlIdentificacion = Url.Action("IdentificacionFacial", "Renegociacion", new { }, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

Voy a poner una captura por si sirve de algo:

[image: kiuwan1]
Tengo varias de este tipo pero no entiendo como solucionarlas.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar o guiar con esto?

Muchas Gracias.